# Why is the page not jumping to the correct part of the screen?

Tags: css, html, hyperlink

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>A+Tec</title>
<style type="text/css" >
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #ABEBC1;
  position: fixed;
}

#nav {
  width: 1400px;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
}

.buttons {
  height: 25x;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #ABEBC1;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family:"Arial Rounded MT Bold", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="nav">
  <div class="buttons">
  </div>
  <div class="buttons"><a href="#C4">About Us</a></div>
  <div class="buttons">Our Staff</div>
  <div class="buttons">New Admissions</div>
  <div class="buttons">A-Level</div>
  <div class="buttons">GCSE</div>
  <div class="buttons">Contact Us</div>
  </div>
</div>
<br/>
<p>
<a href="#C4">See also Chapter 4.</a>
</p>
<h2>Chapter 1</h2>
<p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

<h2>Chapter 2</h2>
<p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

<h2>Chapter 3</h2>
<p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

<h2><a id="C4">Chapter 4</a></h2>
<p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

<h2>Chapter 5</h2>
<p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

<h2>Chapter 6</h2>
<p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

<h2>Chapter 7</h2>
<p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

<h2>Chapter 8</h2>
<p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

<h2>Chapter 9</h2>
<p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

<h2>Chapter 10</h2>
<p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

<h2>Chapter 11</h2>
<p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

<h2>Chapter 12</h2>
<p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

<h2>Chapter 13</h2>
<p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

<h2>Chapter 14</h2>
<p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

<h2>Chapter 15</a></h2>
<p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

<h2>Chapter 16</h2>
<p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>

<h2>Chapter 17</h2>
<p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I have copied and pasted the code from the tryit on w3schools that allows you to jump to any part of the website using a hyperlink here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_locations. When I click on the link "Chapter 4" it jumps to Chapter 2 and when I click on About Us in the top div it goes to the same place. Even if I tried to jump to different parts of the document it keeps jumping to the same part. Why is this?

EDIT: Above seems to be working fine, when I jump to a heading it is hidden behind bar at the top. Is there any way to make it jump to a point where it is underneath the top bar?

Thanks

Comment: Both links work and go to the same spot for me http://jsfiddle.net/D4fRQ/

Comment: yes the problem is that it is the wrong spot

Comment: What's wrong about it? The element with the matching ID goes to the top of the viewport as it should.

Comment: the matching ID is the text "Chapter 4" but it jumps to Chapter 2

Comment: after looking at your link it is working correctly but not if you put it into html file and run?

Comment: Chapter 4 ends up at the top of the viewport for me.

Comment: That's what's supposed to happen. It scolls the chapter to the top of the viewport. If you want middle you'll have to do some additional work. If that's what you want, edit your question

Comment: Edited question. That was not what I wanted originally but it seems to just be my computer that is the problem. How do I change where it jumps to though so that it is not hidden behind top bar?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the ID, you don't need to place it on an `<a>` within the heading. Just use this:

```
<h2 id="C4">Chapter 4</h2>
```

Regarding the clearing of the fixed header, here are some handy articles on the issue:

- http://css-tricks.com/hash-tag-links-padding/
- http://nicolasgallagher.com/jump-links-and-viewport-positioning/demo/

Regarding the links jumping to Chapter 2, it might depend on the height of your browser window. It can only go down as far as the content allows. You'd still see that the Chapter 4 heading is targeted if you used `:target`. E.g

```
#C4:target {background: red;}
```

Comment: I fixed the jumping to chapter 2 problem by adding in line breaks between the divs (bizarre). I am still confused as to how to make the jump so that it does not jump all the way to the top and the text starts below the menu bar